# Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.bustracker.AsyncTaskCallback.onAsyncTaskFinished(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am trying to pass the result from the doInBackground to the onPostExecute() method but I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.bustracker.AsyncTaskCallback.onAsyncTaskFinished(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

What I cant understand I am already checking in the `onPostExecute` whether the arrayList is empty or not but when the output of routes `The output of routes: [3,6,8]` The app crashes but when the arrayList is empty, the app does not crash?!

How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

PostData class:

```
public class PostData {
    String jSONString;
    private AsyncTaskCallback callback;


    public PostData(AsyncTaskCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;

    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public void post_data(String jSONString, Context context) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;

        new MyAsyncTask(context).execute(jSONString);
        // new MyAsyncTask(context).cancel(true);

    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> {

            ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                try {

                    URL myUrl = new URL(
                            "https://bustracker.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                            .openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.connect();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");

                    }
                    System.out.println("StringBuilder: " +sb);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JSONStore data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), JSONStore.class);
                    routes = data.getRoutes();
                    System.out.println("The output of routes: " +routes);



                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                            return null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> result) {

                if (routes != null && !routes.isEmpty()) {
                    callback.onAsyncTaskFinished(routes);
                } else {
                    Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer in the AvailableRoutes class, the routes are null!!!");
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Where did you initialize  callback??

Comment: Agreed. The `ArrayList` is not what is `null`. `callback` is `null`.

Comment: "callback" appears to be null, you're not showing how you initialise it.

Comment: @IgorB: have added the other part of the class I thought it not importnant. Please see my updated question code

Comment: Try to debug `callback `, everything looks fine. I think problem in `callback`, because exception definitely said that `callback is null`

Comment: Ok I solved it that was in the GetAvailableRoute class the constructor of it was commented I added the wrong part of the class I have anothe one to post data.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.bustracker.AsyncTaskCallback.onAsyncTaskFinished(java.util.ArrayList)'
>   on a null object reference

Looks like your interface instance is null. Initialize your AsyncTaskCallback instance.